# Does GitLens have support for git-flow?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-flow, gitlens

I desire to use GitLens to also manage the git-flow structure. 
Does GitLens have a integration for this Git extension? Or is there another extension that has it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you [search the Visual Studio Marketplace for “gitflow”](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=gitflow&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) within VSCode extensions, you can find these two extensions:

- [gitflow](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vector-of-bool.gitflow)
- [GitFlow 4 Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GreatMinds.gitflow4code)

The README of [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) lists all its features, and it doesn’t mention “flow” anywhere, so I assume GitLens does not support it.